# Ошибка: AttributeError: 'BinGrouper' object has no attribute '_groupings'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть данные:

| Time | Price1 | Price2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-24 19:00:00 | 1673.4 | 1624.09 |
| 2021-03-24 20:00:00 | 1637.4 | 1580.18 |
| 2021-03-24 21:00:00 | 1620.79 | 1596.42 |
| 2021-03-24 22:00:00 | 1612.93 | 1536.92 |
| 2021-03-24 23:00:00 | 1597.92 | 1575.1 |
| 2021-03-25 00:00:00 | 1597.94 | 1572.61 |
| 2021-03-25 01:00:00 | 1593.5 | 1553.12 |
| 2021-03-25 02:00:00 | 1580.59 | 1549.4 |
| 2021-03-25 03:00:00 | 1582.41 | 1560.63 |
| 2021-03-25 04:00:00 | 1582.88 | 1564.0 |
| 2021-03-25 05:00:00 | 1592.0 | 1570.59 |
| 2021-03-25 06:00:00 | 1599.0 | 1585.84 |
| 2021-03-25 07:00:00 | 1598.56 | 1572.48 |
| 2021-03-25 08:00:00 | 1604.79 | 1572.65 |
| 2021-03-25 09:00:00 | 1612.5 | 1590.72 |
| 2021-03-25 10:00:00 | 1619.0 | 1598.27 |
| 2021-03-25 11:00:00 | 1622.0 | 1592.26 |
| 2021-03-25 12:00:00 | 1601.03 | 1554.32 |
| 2021-03-25 13:00:00 | 1602.9 | 1561.69 |
| 2021-03-25 14:00:00 | 1613.68 | 1594.16 |
| 2021-03-25 15:00:00 | 1603.74 | 1579.12 |
| 2021-03-25 16:00:00 | 1605.25 | 1570.0 |
| 2021-03-25 17:00:00 | 1609.0 | 1587.0 |
| 2021-03-25 18:00:00 | 1619.0 | 1599.68 |
| 2021-03-25 19:00:00 | 1615.89 | 1600.74 |

Пытаюсь получить максимальное и минимальное значение за 3-х часовой период.

Делаю так:

```
data=pd.concat([data.resample('180T').Price1.rolling(len(data), min_periods=3).max().dropna() , data.resample('180T').Price2.rolling(len(data), min_periods=3).min().dropna() ], axis=1, keys=['Price1', 'Price2'])
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'BinGrouper' object has no attribute '_groupings'
```

Как исправить ошибку? Или может есть способ считать лучше?

---

UPD:
Изначально есть такой список:

```
[[1616659200000,
  '1574.18',
  '1622.54',
  '1573.01',
  '1593.36',
  '421270.841',
  1616673599999,
  '675394628.01520',
  286439,
  '211827.421',
  '339632713.09161',
  '0'],
 [1616673600000,
  '1593.36',
  '1615.61',
  '1555.35',
  '1597.11',
  '703593.509',
  1616687999999,
  '1115403031.53798',
  449625,
  '351390.194',
  '557119635.16550',
  '0'],
 [1616688000000,
  '1597.18',
  '1621.99',
  '1572.82',
  '1606.82',
  '407181.319',
  1616702399999,
  '651268880.88711',
  305126,
  '205206.180',
  '328315238.63720',
  '0'],
 [1616702400000,
  '1606.83',
  '1618.45',
  '1577.65',
  '1587.50',
  '219267.376',
  1616716799999,
  '350660737.62624',
  197251,
  '105071.391',
  '168118894.69875',
  '0'],
 [1616716800000,
  '1587.44',
  '1630.65',
  '1587.03',
  '1619.63',
  '265208.754',
  1616731199999,
  '429206574.64369',
  214865,
  '136382.340',
  '220709131.72386',
  '0'],
 [1616731200000,
  '1619.60',
  '1626.99',
  '1611.20',
  '1619.87',
  '110868.153',
  1616745599999,
  '179569505.70138',
  99601,
  '53066.606',
  '85967606.12833',
  '0'], . . .]
```

И оставляю только две цены и время:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["TimeOpen", "Open", "high", "low", "Close", "Quantity", "TimeClose", "Amount", "Deals","TBB", "TBQ", "Ignore"])
data.Time=data['TimeOpen'].astype(str).str[:-3]
data.drop(['Open', 'Close','Quantity', 'TimeClose', "Amount", "Deals","TBB", "TBQ", "Ignore"], axis=1, inplace=True)
data["TimeOpen"] = pd.to_datetime(data["TimeOpen"], unit="s")
```

Почему-то используя

```
data.rolling("3H", min_periods=3, on="TimeOpen").max()
```

выдает

```
0   2020-10-19 00:00:00   NaN  NaN
1   2020-10-19 04:00:00   NaN  NaN
2   2020-10-19 08:00:00   NaN  NaN
3   2020-10-19 12:00:00   NaN  NaN
4   2020-10-19 16:00:00   NaN  NaN
..                  ...   ...  ...
945 2021-03-25 12:00:00   NaN  NaN
946 2021-03-25 16:00:00   NaN  NaN
947 2021-03-25 20:00:00   NaN  NaN
948 2021-03-26 00:00:00   NaN  NaN
949 2021-03-26 04:00:00   NaN  NaN
```

Мне нужно получить скользящий максимум в столбике high и скользящий минимум в столбике low за 3-х часовой период.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [125]: df.resample("3H", on="Time").max()
Out[125]:
                                   Time   Price1   Price2
Time
2021-03-24 18:00:00 2021-03-24 20:00:00  1673.40  1624.09
2021-03-24 21:00:00 2021-03-24 23:00:00  1620.79  1596.42
2021-03-25 00:00:00 2021-03-25 02:00:00  1597.94  1572.61
2021-03-25 03:00:00 2021-03-25 05:00:00  1592.00  1570.59
2021-03-25 06:00:00 2021-03-25 08:00:00  1604.79  1585.84
2021-03-25 09:00:00 2021-03-25 11:00:00  1622.00  1598.27
2021-03-25 12:00:00 2021-03-25 14:00:00  1613.68  1594.16
2021-03-25 15:00:00 2021-03-25 17:00:00  1609.00  1587.00
2021-03-25 18:00:00 2021-03-25 19:00:00  1619.00  1600.74
```

Или так, если речь идет о скользящем окне:

```
In [128]: df.rolling("3H", min_periods=3, on="Time").max()
Out[128]:
                  Time   Price1   Price2
0  2021-03-24 19:00:00      NaN      NaN
1  2021-03-24 20:00:00      NaN      NaN
2  2021-03-24 21:00:00  1673.40  1624.09
3  2021-03-24 22:00:00  1637.40  1596.42
4  2021-03-24 23:00:00  1620.79  1596.42
5  2021-03-25 00:00:00  1612.93  1575.10
6  2021-03-25 01:00:00  1597.94  1575.10
7  2021-03-25 02:00:00  1597.94  1572.61
8  2021-03-25 03:00:00  1593.50  1560.63
9  2021-03-25 04:00:00  1582.88  1564.00
10 2021-03-25 05:00:00  1592.00  1570.59
11 2021-03-25 06:00:00  1599.00  1585.84
12 2021-03-25 07:00:00  1599.00  1585.84
13 2021-03-25 08:00:00  1604.79  1585.84
14 2021-03-25 09:00:00  1612.50  1590.72
15 2021-03-25 10:00:00  1619.00  1598.27
16 2021-03-25 11:00:00  1622.00  1598.27
17 2021-03-25 12:00:00  1622.00  1598.27
18 2021-03-25 13:00:00  1622.00  1592.26
19 2021-03-25 14:00:00  1613.68  1594.16
20 2021-03-25 15:00:00  1613.68  1594.16
21 2021-03-25 16:00:00  1613.68  1594.16
22 2021-03-25 17:00:00  1609.00  1587.00
23 2021-03-25 18:00:00  1619.00  1599.68
24 2021-03-25 19:00:00  1619.00  1600.74
```

Comment: 1) Изменил в основном коде на ваш пример со скользящим окном. Выдает во всех значениях NaN. Затем запустил свой пример из вопроса и все работает. Данные одинаковы. Не знаете в чем может быть проблема?  2) Как можно только на одну колонку Price1 скользящее окно использовать?

Comment: Выходит почему-то вот так 943 2021-03-25 04:00:00   NaN  NaN
944 2021-03-25 08:00:00   NaN  NaN
945 2021-03-25 12:00:00   NaN  NaN
946 2021-03-25 16:00:00   NaN  NaN
947 2021-03-25 20:00:00   NaN  NaN

Comment: @Denzel, может быть у вас столбец “Time” - это индекс? Попробуйте привести в вопросе __воспроизводимый__ пример данных и желаемый результат. Я не могу воспроизвести ошибку на примере данных из вопроса - у меня все работает

Comment: я обновил. И еще раз проверил. Вроде данные совпадают. Но в чем разница не понимаю.

Comment: еще раз обновил.

Comment: Все решил проблему. Оказывается по невнимательности перепутал список часовой и 4-х часовой. Поэтому выдавало ошибку. Еще раз спасибо!